# How do I run a JavaFX 11 application on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: gradle, javafx, raspberry-pi3, java-11, javafx-11

I have been trying for days now to figure out how to run a JavaFX 11 desktop application I made (using Gradle) on my Raspberry Pi but to no avail.
I have looked at many guides, but most of them use Java 8, or maven, or something else. At this point, I have no idea where to start.

### What I have Tried Before

1. Install `bellsoft openjdk11`
2. Download `openjfx-11` sdk and unzip
3. clone my gradle javafx 11 project from github
4. edit build.gradle to say `sdk=/opt/armv6hf-sdk`
5. chmod +x ./gradlew
6. ./gradlew run

There error I am getting is `could not find :javafx.base:. Searched in the following locations: -file:/opt/armv6hf/lib/javafx.base.jar`

What am I doing wrong?

Do I clone the GitHub repo to my Pi? Do I build it on my Windows machine and then move it over?

**Update**
It now builds, but I am getting an error about `Unable to open DISPLAY` I am 90% sure that this is because I am running raspbian lite (no desktop). How can I run my application *without* running a full desktop enviornment? Is that even possible?

Comment: Did you installed `OpenJDK11`? Follow [this link](https://linuxize.com/post/install-java-on-raspberry-pi/).

Comment: Yes, I do have the OpenJDK `11.0.5-BellSoft`, sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Alright. Please add it to the question body. However, your question is not clear enough.

Comment: BellSoft JavaFX is not usable - it doesn't support Web view, for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you have installed the version of Liberica without JavaFX.

Not too long ago Bell-SW added a "full version" which is found at the bottom of the page.

Please note that you need the normal and not embedded JDK but I don't see that as an issue.

- JDK 13 Armhf (32-bit) tar.gz: https://download.bell-sw.com/java/13.0.2+9/bellsoft-jdk13.0.2+9-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt-full.tar.gz
- JDK 13 Armhf (32-bit) deb: https://download.bell-sw.com/java/13.0.2+9/bellsoft-jdk13.0.2+9-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt-full.deb
- JDK 11 Armhf (32-bit) tar.gz: https://download.bell-sw.com/java/11.0.6+10/bellsoft-jdk11.0.6+10-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt-full.tar.gz
- JDK 11 Armhf (32-bit) deb: https://download.bell-sw.com/java/11.0.6+10/bellsoft-jdk11.0.6+10-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt-full.deb

Source of links: https://bell-sw.com/pages/java-13.0.2/ and https://bell-sw.com/pages/java-11.0.6/

I'd recommend JDK 13 unless you have a reason not to use it.

Comment: I did install the JDK 11 .tar.gz, unziped it, and ran `update-alternatives` for `java` and `javac`. I am now getting an error that says something about `unable to open DISPLAY` I think this is something to do with me runing raspbian with no desktop. I will update my question with this information.

Comment: This question is not what it originally was meant to be. I'd recommend you to open a new question where I can answer without messing up everything. Edit: And yes it is possible, share the link to the new question and mark this as answered because it did actually solve the original issue.

Comment: New question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60580614/getting-errors-when-runing-javafx11-on-raspberry-pi-using-gradle