# Getting errors when runing javafx11 on raspberry pi using gradle

Tags: gradle, raspberry-pi3, java-11, gradlew, javafx-11

I am able to build my javafx11 application, but I get errors when running it using `./gradlew run`

The error I get says something about unable to open DISPLAY

I have tried on both a terminal only install of raspbian and a full desktop install as well.

So far I have done these things:
1) Install bellsoft full jdk
2) git clone gradle project
3) ./gradlew run

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that it didn't work with a Desktop Environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out after much, much more googling. I ended up using `nodm`.

Comment: I'm confused. If it didn't work with a normal Desktop Environment, why does it work with this? Nodm seems to be abandoned and if you can tell me if it really didn't work with a Desktop Environment I can help you to setup Xorg.